Xcode: Expression evaluation failed. Retrying without binding generic parameters
I am not able to print anything in debugger after i installed new Xcode 15.3 in my new Apple m1.
I am getting following errors:
error: Expression evaluation failed. Retrying without binding generic parameters
error: Could not evaluate the expression without binding generic types.

Please help

I encountered the same problem...

I am having the same issue.
I tried to go back to 15.2 thinking 15.3 might be the issue but I had no luck.  I also deleted all the cache just in case. It was working fine with 15.3 till few weeks ago. I have an M2..
